# Trying to remove everything but numbers, but regexes don't seem to work

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove everything but numbers from a variable in PHP. I tried with regexes, and a quick Google turns up all kinds of people telling me to use regexes too, but no regex seems to work. I'm using `preg_replace('/\D/', '', $amount);`. I tried all kinds of different regexes, most notably `/\D/`, `/[\D]/`, `/^\d/`, `/[^\d]/`, and `/[^0-9]/`, but none of them work.

**Edit:** I found why it didn't work! I was under the impression that `preg_replace('/\D/', '', $amount);` would *replace* $amount, but I now see that I have to `$new_amount = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $amount);` and use $new_amount. Stupid, I know. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The user will enter an 'amount' (of money), for example 2,50, which will be sent to my script via GET. I need to provide an amount in cents to my payment provider's API, so I want to remove comma's (in my country comma notation is used), dots or anything else that could confuse my payment provider. So, if the user enters 2,50 or 2.50 (euros) the end result needs to be 250 (cents). I've already dealt with amounts without decimals by adding '00' to the end.

Comment: I suggest leaving decimals and/or commas in the string, otherwise `$2` becomes `0.02`. `preg_replace('/[^0-9.,]/', '', $string);`, then convert to float and multiply by 100 to get your value in cents.

Comment: @Sammitch I dealt with that by checking if the string has any comma's, and if not adding two zeroes. (E.g.: `2` does not have a comma/dot, so it will be made `200` before passing it to `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$amount = '$42,3034534';
// remove extra chars
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9.,]/', '', $amount);
// replace commas with periods, because PHP doesn't like commas as decimals
$str = preg_replace('/,/', '.', $str);
// convert to float and multiply by 100, use floor() to get rid of fractions of a cent
$cents = floor(floatval($str) * 100);
echo $cents;
// OR
echo floor(floatval(preg_replace('/,/', '.', preg_replace('/[^0-9.,]/', '', $amount))) * 100);
//output: 4230
```

Also, stop saying "it doesn't work". *How* is it not working? What result are you getting that is not correct?

Comment: Thanks, but I just figured it out on my own (I wasn't using `preg_replace()` correctly. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$amount = "abc12de3";
$number = preg_replace("/\D/", "", $amount);
echo $number;
```

gives

```
123
```

Comment: To make it clear... its because preg_replace doesn't change $amount, it returns the modified string

Comment: @loosebazooka I just figured that out on my own too! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $amount);
```

This didn't work for you?

Comment: I just figured out that I was, indeed, not using `preg_replace()` correctly. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try the example below. This will remove anything that is not a number from your string.

```
<?php
$string = '!$@^$!!@$^0ls1jlsasl2alfls3ldf4!#$^5jf6k%7==+!*&$#8@(#$(9fdf';
echo preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $string);
//Output: 0123456789
```

You will want to read up on the function [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work...

Edit: I know how `preg_replace()` works, but the problem is that I'm trying all sorts of regexes which should work (such as the one in your example) but they're not working.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then your problem is something else. I have already tested it and that function and it works as expected.

Comment: I just figured out that I was, indeed, not using `preg_replace()` correctly. Thanks anyway!